# AWSのElastic IPの解除ができません。

Tags: aws

EIPはEC2インスタンスに割り当てていたのですが、
[アクション]->[アドレスの関連付けの解除]を押して解除しようとすると

You do not have permission to access the specified resource.

というエラーが出て解除ができません。
同じ操作をEC2インスタンスの起動中にも削除後にも行いましたが同じです。

もしご存知の方がいらっしゃったらご教示願います

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10177290475

Answer (score 1):

rootユーザーを使用しての操作でしょうか？
そうではない場合、ユーザーのIAMへAmazonEC2FullAccessのポリシーをアタッチして再度試して見て下さい。